# Why enclosing a call in a lambda if calling it immediately?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, c++11, lambda

A piece of code that I am looking at encapsulates some calls to functions in a DLL into lambdas that are executed immediately:

```
try {
    [] { call_a_function(); } ();
}
catch (const char* msg) {
    //...
}
```

I don't see why this would be different from just a plain call to the function, which compiles just fine.

```
try {
    call_a_function();
}
catch (const char* msg) {
    //...
}
```

What am I missing here?
This code is using Visual Studio 2012, if that's of any importance...

Comment: It makes the code look more emotionally comforting to a recovering JavaScript user.

Comment: Compare the resulting assembler to see the difference.

Comment: If you see code like this during a code review, the person responsible for it better have thick skin ... he's going to need it after the flogging he's going to take.

Comment: @till: It may be that the generated code is not the same, but I'm more interested in an answer that would describe a difference _in semantics_ between the two.

Comment: If that's the exact code, I can't see any reason whatsoever to wrap the call in a lambda. It's nonsense.

Comment: @TonyD, I would accept your answer if you added it...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's of extremely dubious practical use, but functionally the lambda's `[]` capture prevents (compilation error) accidental use of a function-local "call_a_function". For example, a preceding `auto call_a_function = [] { ... };` would trigger a "not captured" error, whereas a simple function call would execute the call using that local definition.

You mention "some calls to functions" - if others have parameters this becomes a smidge more relevant, as the capture list might be used to copy a parameter rather than give the called function potentially non-const-reference access to a function's local variable.  It might be for stylistic consistency that even this parameter-less call adopts the lambda style.

Otherwise Till's comment's as good as it gets - e.g. it may be a particular compiler did or didn't inline the lambda, and that was important to the original developer - would be a horrible way to hack it though.